# Get value of the third column in a table in selectedindex changed event of dropdown list in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my code to display table value to a `DropDownList`.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ConnectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    string str="SELECT ItemOne,ItemTwo,ItemThree  FROM tableItem";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter dA=new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        dA.Fill(dT);
        DropDownList1.DataSource = dT;
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ItemTwo";
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "ItemOne";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
    }
```

This is to display the selected value of `DropDownList` to a `TextBox`.

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      TextBox1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
      TextBox2.Text = //Get the value of ItemThree here
}
```

My problem is: How will I display the column value of `ItemThree` in another `TextBox`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ConnectionString;
var sql = "SELECT ItemOne, ItemTwo, ItemThree FROM tableItem";
using (var table = new DataTable) {
    using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connectionString)
        adapter.Fill(table);
    foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr["ItemTwo"], dr["ItemTwo"]) {
            Tag = dr["ItemThree"]
        });
}
```

Then from the event handler

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      TextBox1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
      TextBox2.Text = DropdownList1.SelectedItem.Tag.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object' error appear

Comment: @odlanyer Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      TextBox1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
      TextBox2.Text = DropDownList1.Items[2].ToString(); // 2 is your index
    }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post

Comment: This only works on the first selected event click, but on succeeding click it wont work.